# DbSchemaException after updating ObjectBox version

Tags: android, objectbox

i'm facing a strange issue after updating the ObjectBox Version , from 2.9.1 to 3.4.0, in my Android App. The App crashes on initialization of the BoxStore with:

```
Caused by: io.objectbox.exception.DbSchemaException: DB's last property ID 5 is higher than the incoming one 4 in entity ThingState
```

I checked the `default.json`, after updating, ObjectBox added/updated some flag entries but other than this, there was no change in ID oder UID of any Entity or Property. Also the underlying entity Class was not changed at all.

```
    {
      "id": "20:9092038177056300326",
      "lastPropertyId": "4:6225405887985272080",
      "name": "ThingState",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:8694189551848819348",
          "name": "localId",
          "type": 6,
          "flags": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "2:6118656856190995317",
          "name": "since",
          "type": 10
        },
        {
          "id": "3:1419132902384979209",
          "name": "current",
          "type": 5
        },
        {
          "id": "4:6225405887985272080",
          "name": "thingId",
          "indexId": "17:3214967715451997464",
          "type": 11,
          "flags": 520,
          "relationTarget": "Thing"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    }
```

I also looked at the official [troubleshooting](https://docs.objectbox.io/troubleshooting) page, but could not find anything that fits the situation, since there was no change in entity class or `default.json` file. When I downgrade back to 2.9.1 it starts working again.

Is there something i can do to fix this, or is this due to a breaking change in mayor version bump?

Comment: Please also check https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/data-model-updates - it does not look like a upgrade issue, but rather like a "user error".

Comment: Thx for the reply @MarkusJunginger . But I can't find anything that helps in my situation since the data model was not updated.

Comment: "DB's last property ID 5 is higher than the incoming one 4 in entity ThingState" tells that there was a property present that got removed.

Comment: @MarkusJunginger yes, that much is clear. The irritating part is, that the Entity ThingState was not changed. The last change on that entity was 2 years ago. And the same Entity works with the older version 2.9.1. I checked the ObjectBox Admin and the Entity has only 4 Properties.

Comment: As a workaround, you could change lastPropertyId to something like "lastPropertyId": "6:6767676767676767676767" (ID:UID; UID is anything as long it's unique)

Comment: @MarkusJunginger no, sadly not working. But i just added another property to the entity and it looks like it is working now. Still have no clue what went wrong.